# Monads do not compose, right?

Tags: monads, purescript

While I was researching for a talk I came across something that I thought was not possible, and I still can't figure out why it is working. In the `Control.Bind` module, there is the definition of the fish operator:

```
composeKleisli ∷ ∀ a b c m. Bind m ⇒ (a → m b) → (b → m c) → a → m c
```

The documentation above it gives an example:

```
third = tail >=> tail >=> head
```

This is where my mind doesn't compute. I thought it would never compile* and yet it does:

```
> :t tail >=> tail >=> head
forall t2. Array t2 -> Maybe t2
```

How can this be? Clearly `tail` and `head` differ in the output `m`.

* or that the type checker would infer the following type: `forall t2. Array (Array t2) -> Array t2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, `m` in that case is `Maybe`, hence you do not need to compose different type of monads.

More specifically:

```
tail :: forall a. Array a -> Maybe (Array a)
head :: forall a. Array a -> Maybe a
```

So

```
composeKliesli tail tail :: forall a. Array a → Maybe (Array a)
composeKliesli (composeKliesli tail tail) head :: forall a. Array a -> Maybe a
```

To see that you need to substitute `m` with `Maybe` and `a`, `b` and `c`s with either `a` or `Array a` in the type of `composeKliesli`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I mistakenly thought `tail` returned an array no matter what 